# PHPStorm: Generate filename on custom file template

Tags: phpstorm

## PHP Storm: File templates

I would like to add custom file template with generated filename. I do not want to prompt filename by hand, I want it generated with variable values.

E.g. ${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}_${MyCustomVar}.sql

It there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would you like to create files with 'fixed' names generated using temploate variables? It's not currently possible - you can file a request for this feature to youtrack (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)
Related ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6428